# how does foreach works in react-redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, foreach, react-redux

I am making a nodejs app which can fetch flights from the KIWI api, it returns a json list, and since you parameters like from and to, it should return a list of flights.

I can successfully get that, but when I want to display everything I dont know how to do it.

This is my render:

```
render(){
        return (
            <table className="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Flight #</th>
                        <th>From</th>
                        <th>To</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.flights.map(this.renderFlights)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
```

and

```
renderFlights(flightData){
        // add key to make them unique
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>{flightData.data[0].id}</td>
                <td>{flightData.data[0].mapIdfrom}</td>
                <td>{flightData.data[0].mapIdto}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
```

`{this.props.flights.map(this.renderFlights)}` just maps the first one in the array, I know that I have to use `foreach`, but I dont know how I can use this to print everything in the list, flight id plus the from and to, so when u fetch the flights u get around 15, and I want to be able to display all the 15 flights can someone help me out here?

this returns undefined for `forEach`:

```
 <tbody>
                        {
                            this.props.flights.array.forEach(element => {
                                this.renderFlights
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Why are you doing flightData.data[0].id ? Can you post the structure of your this.props.flights ?

Comment: @user222957 do u want my flightReducer?

Comment: You definitely want to use map, don't use foreach because it doesn't return anything

Comment: I mean can you console.log your this.props.flights

Comment: @user222957 IT RETURNS json file and it has so many info, but I need the data part that holds all the flights.

Comment: I've never used foreach like that in react, because it doesn't work. Also, I can't help you if I don't know what's inside your "this.props.flights". Can you console.log it?

Comment: @user222957 returns something like this `{search_params: {…}, _results: 15, connections: Array(0), currency: "EUR", currency_rate: 1, …}`

Comment: If it logs an object, then "this.props.flights" is not an array, and you shouldn't map over it. Most likely, there is an array inside "this.props.flights" that contains what you want. But it's probably not called "array", maybe some other name. Can you find it?

Comment: there is a data inside of it but when I do `this.renderFlights.data` it retuens undefined!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation for your kiwi api? Something that tells you exactly what the object is, and what it should contain....

Comment: https://locations10.docs.apiary.io/#

Comment: @user222957  I realized that this.props.flights[0] returns another list which has data inside of it which holds all the flight I want, but If I do this.props.flights[0].data i get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: The API link your sent me gives me a list of locations, not flights. https://locations10.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/locations-collection/search-by-query?console=1 Are you sure you used that api?

Comment: https://skypickerpublicapi.docs.apiary.io/#reference/flights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found your API and test interface here: https://skypickerbookingapi1.docs.apiary.io/#reference/check-flights/checkflights/check_flights?console=1

So it seems that you are getting this object for your response:

```
{
  "server_time": 1516568910,
  "flights_checked": false,
  "extra_fee": 0,
  // blah blah,

  "flights": [

    // first flight 

    {
      "bags_recheck_required": false,
      "dtime_unix": 1524646800,
      "extra": "",
      "atime_unix": 1524651600,
      "priority_boarding": {
        "currency": null,
        "price": null,
        "is_possible": false
      },
      "price": 313,
      "currency": "NOK",
      "price_new": 313,
      // blah blah
    },

    // second flight
   {
      "bags_recheck_required": true,
      "dtime_unix": 1524683400,
      "extra": "",
      "atime_unix": 1524691800,
      "priority_boarding": {
        "currency": null,
        "price": null,
        "is_possible": false
      },
      "price": 1560,
      "currency": "NOK",
      "price_new": 1560,
      // blah blah
   },
   // more and more flights
```

So I'm guessing that your "this.props.flights" is referring to the "flights" property of the above object.

Now, you need to use "map", not "foreach":

```
this.props.flights.map(this.renderFlights) //this is correct
```

And your callback function should be:

```
renderFlights(one_single_flight){
        // add key to make them unique
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>{one_single_flight.id}</td>
                <td>{one_single_flight.src_country}</td>
                <td>{one_single_flight.dst_country}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer. You should NOT use forEach as it does not return anything, whereas map does.

Comment: THANKS GUYS, THIS IS CORRECT BUT i WANT EVERY FLIGHT IN THAT LIST NOT JUST ONE.

Comment: I know. The "renderFlights" callback will be run multiple times by the "map" function, and one_single_flight will become whatever flight it's currently looping over. But if your code works, then that's all that matters :) Good luck and thanks for the upvote

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to get the result I wanted:

```
renderFlights(flightData){
    const result = flightData._results;       
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result; i++) {
        rows.push(
        <tr key={i} >
            <td>{flightData.data[i].mapIdfrom}</td>,
            <td>{flightData.data[i].mapIdto}</td>,
        </tr>
        );
    }
    return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
}
```

This prints all the available flights for some certain date.